# Are the lags of all selected variables equal to its current values

Tags: r

I have a dataset as this

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), var1 = c(1,1,2,2), var2 = c(1,1,2,3))
```

and I am trying to each this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), var1 = c(1,1,2,2), var2 = c(1,1,2,3), same = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

i.e. such that the result is TRUE only if for every variable the diff of the variable is eqal to 0.
I can do it manually if I know the names of all variables, but that is tedious and cannot be repeated for other datasets, where I do not know the names nor the number or variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), var1 = c(1,1,2,2), var2 = c(1,1,2,3)) 

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('var'), ~.x == lag(.x), .names = '{col}_res')) %>%
  mutate(same = rowSums(!select(., ends_with('res'))) == 0) %>%
  select(-ends_with('res'))

#  id var1 var2  same
#1  1    1    1    NA
#2  2    1    1  TRUE
#3  3    2    2 FALSE
#4  4    2    3 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work, only what would you do if the name of vars were not homogeneous as "var x"?

Comment: If there is no pattern in the column names then you can apply the function using column numbers. `across` also accepts column numbers.

Comment: Please help me understand the meaning of ~ in the code though, otherwide I understand everything.
One more thing, if I wanted to introduce multiple comditions, such as "diff is 0 and at the same time the varible is equal to 1"? I thought its going to be just a simple expansion of the code with the condition, but it doesnt work for me

Comment: `~` is a formula based syntax which is used to apply a function here. It is an alternative to anonymous function which can be used with `function(x) x == lag(x)`. You can perhaps expand the function to something like this `.x == lag(.x) == 0 & .x == 1`. This will give diff = 0 and variable = 1.

Comment: Cant seem to make that work. Is it possible to have 2 == in a row? Even if I replace the first == with -, it says that "object .x not found" and when I replace it with ~.x, it says "Input must be a vector, not a `formula` object."

Comment: It would be better if you ask that as a new question instead of extending it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diff` and `rowSums` to test *if variables are equal to their previous values*.

```
x$same <- c(NA, rowSums(diff(as.matrix(x[-1]))) == 0)
x
#  id var1 var2  same
#1  1    1    1    NA
#2  2    1    1  TRUE
#3  3    2    2 FALSE
#4  4    2    3 FALSE
```

Comment: How would it look in the case that there is an unknown number of columns before our var1 .... varn? And also if the NA would be introduced organically, just because for the first row, the difference cannot be done? Also, is there a solution for this when inside of dplyr pipe, with mutate() ?

Comment: You can select the columns to be considered by changing the part `x[-1]` to something which subsets to the desired columns e.g. `x[2:3]`.